# How to circuit a motor with led

Tags: led, motor

I want to make a fan with led. I have a motor and led which are from old toys and torchlight. I not sure about their "specs" but this are their operating voltage and method:
Motor:
using two AAA batteries, 3V
Led:
using three 1.5V button cells, 4.5V, not sure about the amperages,
How can I circuit it with 5V USB with 1A? Just need some help on resistor. Parallel or series circuit work? If I have any wrong please tell me.
p/s:sorry for my grammar, I'm not a native speaker of english

Comment: Measure those currents first.

Comment: I agree you should really have measured currents first. However, if you can't do that then a starting point might be to chose 10mA for the LED and 100mA for the motor giving values of about 220R for the LED and 22R for the motor.